# Insert user password into e-mail body sent by Rules for Ubercart's order completion

Tags: 6, ubercart, rules, tokens, users

I have a Rules for Ubercart

```
Event: Order Checkout Complete
Do :  Send a mail to a user
```

I need to insert the password of the user the mail is sent to but there is no token for it.

How can I insert the user password into the mail body set by Rules modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible because Drupal saves hash of passwords in the database, so you can't access the original password.